# How to download the streaming response of a POST request into a file?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, download, stream

So I would like to serve large files for download from a Java EE (JAX-RS) application server to a browser-based Javascript client. The content does not fit into the memory on either server or client side, so only streaming or chunks are appropriate. The content depends on POST parameters and HTTP headers, including user name and password for decryption, so a simple GET based download is not desirable. Content has to be available for download as a file. Only Firefox and Chrome have to be supported.

On server side the solution is pretty straightforward, JAX-RS has StreamingOutput specifically for streaming responses. On client side however I do not see an obvious solution. Javascript + HTML + HTTP do not apparently support my requirements. Some possible solutions that I have investigated:

- Forget POST parameters and HTTP headers, send everything in the URL of a GET request. This is not desirable since username and password are also sent in the address.
- Put the parameters into a HTML form with hidden inputs, and then submit to a _blank target. This complicates things since we must use application/x-www-form-urlencoded (or multipart/form-data) instead of application/json for the POST parameters.
- HTTP byte range headers. As far as I know they can only be used with GET requests, and not with POST.
- Download content with AJAX, create a new HTML5 link with data URI, and click on it. Example is . This approach does not scale, it runs out of memory after a few hundred megabytes.
- Cache results on server side, and provide a unique ID for download with GET. Unfortunately at the moment we do not have any space nor memory for caching results.
- Custom XMLHttpRequest.responseType. Unfortunately moz-chunked-arraybuffer and ms-stream are browser specific non-standard features. Furthermore, download still has to be solved.
- I glanced at https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js but it seems very overkill and has no support for Firefox.
- Streams API, Fetch API. No ReadableStream support in Firefox.

So basically there is no perfect solution that would fulfill all of my requirements without compromises. I am open to suggestions if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: If you respond to an HTTP request with the file content as an attachment, the browser will prompt with the standard "Save File" dialog and handle saving the file on the client for you.

Comment: So do what we have done for ages. Post a form to a window/iframe with the headers set for download.